# Should I stop using a deprecated module?

Tags: python, module, warnings, deprecated

I am using django-registration v0.7 and django 1.2.4. Everything works fine but I am wondering why I'm getting this warning message each time I run the server:

```
 C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py:4: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprec
    ated; use the hashlib module instead
      import sha
```

Could be a problem in the future? Can I avoid it without changing django-registration original code?

**EDIT**
This deprecation warning comes up in Python 2.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This deprecation warning comes up in Python 2.6 and django-registration v0.7, it dissapears upgrading django-registration to v0.8

Answer (score 3):

No, if it works, leave it. You can consider this something to think about when you upgrade to a new version of Python which actually removes this module.

Deprecated means that you are encouraged not to use it in new code, it doesn't mean you need to modify (and hence break) existing code which uses it.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins But he's not writing code that uses it, he's using code that already uses it and is known to work.

Answer (score 3):

you should create new issue/ticket/bug on project's site, or report this to developers of the project.
if there is no activity in project, you are free to fix the code locally.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and kept getting mail about a **cron job** which was throwing deprecation warning so i ran my python script with

```
-W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

since the script is running in a virtualenv which won't be moving to py3k i can live with this